# SELinux : Where I find selinux policy for google-chrome on Fedora Linux?

Tags: fedora, chrome, selinux

How do I find all the SELinux policies used for Google Chrome on Fedora Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep /opt/google /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/file_contexts 
/opt/google/[^/]*/.*\.so    --  system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
/opt/google/chrome(/.*)?    system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
/opt/google-earth/.*\.so.*  --  system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/wdi    --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/wine.* --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/msiexec    --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/notepad    --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/progman    --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/regedit    --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/regsvr32   --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/chrome[^/]*/chrome-sandbox  --  system_u:object_r:chrome_sandbox_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/Picasa3/.*exe  --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa(/.*)?/bin/uninstaller    --  system_u:object_r:wine_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/chrome[^/]*/nacl_helper_bootstrap   --  system_u:object_r:chrome_sandbox_nacl_exec_t:s0
/opt/google/chrome/.*\.so   --  system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa/.*\.dll  --  system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
/opt/google/picasa/.*\.yti  --  system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
/opt/google/talkplugin(/.*)?    system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
/opt/google/talkplugin/.*\.so   --  system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
/opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper_bootstrap    --  system_u:object_r:chrome_sandbox_nacl_exec_t:s0
```

Source: https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy/search?q=%2Fopt%2Fgoogle